# Django pass parameters

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass pk key

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api/products', ProductAPI.as_view()),
path('api-admin/products/', ProductAdminAPI.as_view()),
url(r'^api-admin/products/(?P<pk>[0-9]\d+)', ProductAdminAPI.as_view()),
]
```

with this URL `localhost:8000/api-admin/products/3/`

but I'm getting 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `(?P<pk>[0-9]\d+)` is wrong. You need at least 2 digits to match the expression, since you first ask a character `[0-9]` and then a digit `\d`.

Remove either `[0-9]` or `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing 
`url(r'^api-admin/products/(?P<pk>[0-9]\d+)', ProductAdminAPI.as_view()),`
with 
`path('api-admin/products/<int:pk>', ProductAdminAPI.as_view())` Will also get the job done.